# UserService, OAuth, and AJAX in App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm running a webapp that checks if a user is logged in with `UserService`, then shows them their homepage if they are, or redirects them to a login screen if not. Once on the page, I would like to be able to update specific portions using `AJAX` when they click certain elements. Now, I have already written a `REST` API in the same GAE project using Cloud Endpoints that gets all the information I want, and so in the spirit of DRY I would rather use my own API than write new servlets to handle these requests.

The problem is that I need to generate an `OAuth` token in order to access the API. I can easily do this from the Google API JavaScript Client Library, but then my user needs to re-authenticate for the rest API, which is not only bad from a UX perspective, but more importantly exposes my client id in the page's javascript and passes a token through `HTTP` (non-`SSL`) headers.

The only option I see is to write a servlet for each request and have duplicate work. But conceptually, *I'm already logged in to Google*, so I should just be able to access the API. How does one usually go about this? Am I thinking about it all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UserService` and OAuth are two different authentication (and authorisation) mechanisms and you can not combine them.

If you do need OAuth to access some of the APIs than also use [server side OAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer). This way you can access APIs and replace `UserService` all in one go.

Comment: I would say that endpoints does combine those two services: it uses OAuth to authenticate a google user, resulting in a 'User' instance (same as you would get from UserService.getCurrentUser.)

Comment: He's differentiating between the `OAuthService` class and `UserService` classes. Which, although both generate a `User` instance, can't be simultaneously used for authentication. I actually just ended up making a pure web client with `Angular.js` that makes calls to the API and nothing else. So no more authentication necessary on the server side besides the one baked into `Cloud Endpoints`.